# For $2 \times 2$ matrix, if $AB = -BA$, what properties would $A$ and $B$ have with regards to each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As title says, assume that $A$ and $B$ are two-by-two matrices. I want them to satisfy $AB = -BA$. What properties do these two matrices have with regards to each other? Sufficient properties would be fine; it doesn't have to be necessary conditions.

Also, $AB \neq 0$.

Comment: For necessay conditions see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185457/matrices-conditions-for-abba-0

Comment: @user127.0.0.1: Like $A=B=I_2$???

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen of course, thanks. for idempotent matrices it holds $AB-BA=0$ not $AB+BA=0$

Comment: Note that we get $ABA = A(BA) = A(-AB)= -A^2 B$ so if $b$ is invertible then $B A B^{-1} = -A$: $A$ is similar to $-A$, so all eigenvalues of $A$ must be zero. So only possible interesting solutions are singular.